# Sort categorical x-axis in a seaborn plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stripplot

I am trying to plot the top 30 percent values in a data frame using a seaborn scatter plot as shown below.

[image]

The reproducible code for the same plot:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#function to return top 30 percent values in a dataframe.
def extract_top(df):
    n = int(0.3*len(df))
    top = df.sort_values('sepal_length', ascending = False).head(n)

    return top

#storing the top values
top = extract_top(df)

#plotting
sns.scatterplot(data = top,
                x='species', y='sepal_length', 
                color = 'black',
                s = 100,
                marker = 'x',)
```

Here, I want sort the x-axis in `order = ['virginica','setosa','versicolor']`. When I tried to use `order` as one of the parameter in `sns.scatterplot()`, it returned an error `AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'order'`. What is the right way to do it?

Please note: In the dataframe, `setosa` is also a category in `species`, however, in the top 30% values non of its value is falling. Hence, that label is not shown in the example output from the reproducible code at the top. But I want even that label in the x-axis as well in the given order as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`scatterplot()` is not the correct tool for the job. Since you have a categorical axis you want to use `stripplot()` and not `scatterplot()`. See the difference between relational and categorical plots here https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html

```
sns.stripplot(data = top,
              x='species', y='sepal_length', 
              order = ['virginica','setosa','versicolor'],
              color = 'black', jitter=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. However, Why is it not displaying markers '+' or 'x' with ````marker=```` in the ````sns.stripplot()````?

Comment: I was investigating this, I answered your other question.

Answer (score 1):

This means `sns.scatterplot()` does not take `order` as one of its `args`. For species `setosa`, you can use `alpha` to hide the scatter points while keep the ticks.

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#function to return top 30 percent values in a dataframe.
def extract_top(df):
    n = int(0.3*len(df))
    top = df.sort_values('sepal_length', ascending = False).head(n)

    return top

#storing the top values
top = extract_top(df)
top.append(top.iloc[0,:])
top.iloc[-1,-1] = 'setosa'
order = ['virginica','setosa','versicolor']

#plotting
for species in order:
    alpha = 1 if species != 'setosa' else 0
    sns.scatterplot(x="species", y="sepal_length",
                    data=top[top['species']==species],
                    alpha=alpha,
                    marker='x',color='k')
```

the output is

[image: output]

Comment: I edited the question. Please look into it and suggest changes to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, if the ````order = [ 'virginica','setosa','versicolor']```` then? In the above code, it is leaving one space for one category variable and continuing displaying the scatter but not actually plotting based on the x-axis.

Comment: Rather than playing with the 'xticks' every time, is it not possible to set it by default within the scatterplot() or another way? As it will be difficult in reality if many categories are available and many plots have to be plotted.

Comment: @Ganesh thank you for this question, I never thought about these before, yes you can, check out my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to make use of the extra arguments available in sns.scatterplot over sns.strpplot (size and style mappings for variables), it's possible to set the order of the x axis simply by sorting the dataframe before passing it to seaborn. The following will sort alphabetically.

```
df.sort_values(feature)
```