# Seaborn Scatterplot - Order the X axis lables

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the name of the day of the week on the x-axis of my seaborn **scatterplot**.

I want to order it according to the following natural order

```
cats = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

I tried following which is working for other plot types:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Time', hue='Type', order= cats)
```

But gives me an error: it seems like order is not in the scatterplot func. How to solve this?

```
  File "/..lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 970, in _update_property
.format(type(self).__name__, k))
 AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'order'
```

Comment: The answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64765375/8881141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead of order:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Day', y='time', hue_order= ['cats'])
```

[image: screenshot of code]